# How Run Php Script Silently include javascript with use cronjob

Tags: javascript, php

I need to run a php script that includes javascript and ajax every 10 min or 20 minutes.

I can run pure php script but if the php script includes javascript then it doesn't work.

I think this is because I need to use any browser engine silently.

How can I go about solving this problem? I need to use the javascript in the php.

Comment: O_o what exactly do you want to do? It seems there's a better solution

Comment: Well, you could command the cron to open a browser and open a specific page, maybe this works ... but srsly, if you have to use javascript in a cronjob, you did something wrong.

Comment: That's not possible. PHP-CLI will not execute JS-Code. Even if you've a cronjob that will exec a `wget` the JS-Code will not be executed.
Describe your problem a little bit more.

Comment: @createproblem uhm, can lynx execute javascript? Just a thought, pretty unsure to be honest.

Comment: Is there no way to use client browser engine silently ?

Comment: @Y U NO WORK short answer no Lynx doesn't support Javascript.

Comment: @user3222643 you can do that, like with phantomjs, but there is almost certainly a better way to do what you need. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Upvoted question? What for? D: So many reason to close vote, I can't even decide

Comment: I got canvas charts then I want to send me email its report every day.

Comment: You should search a server-side charting library, it'll simplify your life on the long term.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) - a headless WebKit browser with full javascript support which you can call and interact with via PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run JavaScript directly in a PHP Script.

If you want to run JavaScript server-side, look at using something such as [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)

Comment: Really how do you do that. PHP has not JS interpreter. Execute JS-Code inside PHP is not possible as far as i know. And Server-Side Js-Code != Client-Side eg. jQuery. You can't execute JS-Client-Side-Code with nodejs. You will not have the same behaver.

Comment: It depends what behavior the OP is looking to get out of this. I highly doubt it's user-interaction based behavior if OP is looking to automate it.